# chromedriver headless alerts

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I have this issue with selenium webdriver tests with chromedriver. Although I can run tests succesfully when using Chrome browser I can't run the same tests in headless mode.

I cannot handle the Js alerts. Actually when taking a screenshot it seems that the alert won't even pop-up.

[Alert screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXt4G.png)

I have tried several workarounds:

1) `driver.window_handles` --> No other window seems to be present

2) `driver.execute_script("window.confirm = function(){return true;}")` --> Nothing changed with that script

3) `element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.alert_is_present())` and of course an explicit wait

In browser mode I use a plain:

```
try:
    print driver.switch_to.alert.text
    driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
except NoAlertPresentException as e: 
    print("no alert")
```

Anyone else having this issue with alerts in headless mode?

- chromedriver v.2.30.477691
- Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Still having this problem as of Chrome 61, so I spent a while looking for a different solution. My favorite because of it's simplicity is injecting javascript before the alert is shown in order to automatically accept the alert.

Just put the following line of code *before* the line that causes the alert to be shown:

```
driver.ExecuteJavaScript("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");
```

Works with both headless chrome and PhantomJS.

Comment: That BEFORE is crucial. So guys put this line before the `element.click()` and just to add for python do `driver.execute_script("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");`

Comment: Hello guys, I have the same situation that in headless mode, the popup is not recognised. Tried to follow above code. But it errors for using "ExecuteJavaScript". Am I doing something wrong? Is it userdefined function? if it is what exactly i need to code.

Comment: Am i correct if I follow like this, ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");

Comment: It should work exactly as above (using selenium and C#). The code in your second comment doesn't make any sense to me. Maybe you're missing a reference or a using somewhere?

Comment: I was having this issue and this worked for me with a slight modification using NightwatchJS (this.api is the same in this case as browser.perform() ):


this.api.perform(function () { this.confirm = function () { return true; }})

Answer (score 3):

It seems that I have the same issue when running headless chrome.
The alert window does not pop up base on the screen shots. It works fine on chrome but not headless chrome.

I am running on chrome  60.0.3112.72
and chrome driver 2.30

Because the headless chrome automatically discards alerts.
check this:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=718235

---

BTW, how come you can screen shot in chrome 59 in headless mode? chrome 59 has a bug that makes every screen shot a 1x1 pixel image in headless mode, so I upgraded to chrome 60.

Comment: I don't know but this works for me.. `driver.save_screenshot("ss.png")` but lets stay on topic

Answer (score 2):

Since Chrome headless doesn't (currently) support alerts, you have to monkeypatch the `alert()` and `confirm()` methods. This is the approach I've used (in C#):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The Chrome Headless driver doesn't support alerts, so we need to override the window.alert method to get the expected behavior.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="driver">The active IWebDriver instance</param>
    /// <param name="result">The result that the alert should return, i.e., true if we want it "accepted", false if we don't</param>
    public static void SetupAlert(this IWebDriver driver, bool result)
    {
        // ks 7/27/17 - The Chrome Headless driver doesn't support alerts, so override the various window.alert methods to just set 
        const string scriptTemplate = @"
window.alertHandlerCalled = false;
window.alertMessage = null;
window.alert = window.confirm = function(str) {
    window.alertHandlerCalled = true;
    window.alertMessage = str;
    return {{result}};
};";

        var script = scriptTemplate.Replace("{{result}}", result.ToString().ToLower());
        var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        js.ExecuteScript(script);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is an optional accompaniment to the <see cref="SetupAlert"/> method, which checks to see
    /// if the alert was, in fact, called. If you don't want to bother to check, don't worry about calling it.
    /// Note that this doesn't reset anything, so you need to call <see cref="SetupAlert"/> each time before calling
    /// this method.
    /// </summary>
    public static void WaitForAlert(this IWebDriver driver, TimeSpan? timeout = null)
    {
        const string script = @"return window.alertHandlerCalled";
        var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        var timeToBail = DateTime.Now.Add(timeout ?? TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        while (DateTime.Now < timeToBail)
        {
            var result = (bool)js.ExecuteScript(script);
            if (result) return;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The alert was not called.");
    }
```

I use it like this:

```
        Driver.SetupAlert(true);
        this.ClickElement(ResetButton);
        Driver.WaitForAlert();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add this in case someone comes across this issue using NightwatchJS.

The above accepted solution worked for me, but using JS it needed a slight modification from

```
driver.ExecuteJavaScript("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");
```

I needed to change it to

```
// this.api.perform() in my case is the same as browser.perform() 
this.api.perform(function () { this.confirm = function () { return true; }})
```