# Unable to handle Microsoft login authentication popup in headless chrome[Selenium using java]

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, windows-authentication, google-chrome-headless

I am automating the web application to run in Headless Chrome. 
ChromeDriver Version:- ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6
Application Login screen has windows popup to enter username and password. I used alerts to handle the popup in normal chrome

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 18);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.sendKeys("username" + Keys.TAB + "password");
alert.accept();
```

When Chrome is set to headless, windows popup is not displaying. I could only see blank screen in screenshots.

Also, i tried adding the chromeoptions as

```
String path = "path to chromedriver";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "./chromedriver.log");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

ChromeDriverLog has the default values as

```
"default_content_settings": {
         "geolocation": 1,
         "mouselock": 1,
         "notifications": 1,
         "popups": 1,
         "ppapi-broker": 1
      }
```

Comment: How do you handle windows pop up using Alert. Do you mean web based pop-ups?
This looks to be a bug with headless chrome. See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242264/chromedriver-headless-alerts

Answer (score 5):

With the current implementation of *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome* using `switchTo().alert()` may not the best possible way to work through **Basic Authentication** functionality. Instead, an *ideal* and *elegant* way would be to embedded the credentials in subresource requests. An example:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.io.IOException;

  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

  public class BasicAuthentication_Chrome 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.navigate().to("http://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth");
      }
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Basic Auth]

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Selenium - Basic Authentication via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345882/selenium-basic-authentication-via-url/45352660#45352660)

---

### Basic Authentication in headless mode

With `--headless` mode being *enabled* **Basic Authentication** still works as expected. An example:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.IOException;

  import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
  import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
  import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

  public class BasicAuthentication_Chrome 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.addArguments("--headless");
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.navigate().to("http://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth");
          Thread.sleep(3000);
          File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
          FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(".\\Screenshots\\headless.png"));
      }
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Basic Auth]

---

### Outro

[Python Windows Authentication username and password is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328654/python-windows-authentication-username-and-password-is-not-working/45329228#45329228)