# Cannot open dialog or alert boxes in playwright browsers

Tags: javascript, firefox, webkit, chromium, playwright

- When trying to click buttons that should have triggered an alert, playwright browsers(chromium, webkit, and firefox) just flickers and does not display it.
- I tried downloading an actual chromium browser in my windows machine and was able to display the alert box.
- Also tried it in firefox and had no problems displaying the alert box.
- playwright version : 1.10.0
- OS : windows 10
- Also looked into popups under privacy settings and it's set as allowed.
- Help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine suggested a work around to this problem that can be found in [chromedriver headless alerts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242264/chromedriver-headless-alerts)

For some reason, the app that we're developing can't properly display the dialog boxes which worked perfectly on other sites.

To handle the dialog boxes, we can simply insert the code like. This is only to mock user action confirming the dialog box.

```
 await this.page.evaluate(() => window.confirm = function(){return true;});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve that without hacking the browser.

```
def on_dialog(dialog: Dialog):
    dialog.accept()


page.on("dialog", on_dialog)
page.evaluate("alert('yo')")
```